# Spring Cloud Task Scheduling Context Closed

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I run my task without the CommandLineRunner implemented and add the @Scheduled annotation it appears the context is being closed. How can I keep the context open so the @Scheduled can run properly?

DataTransferTask.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DataTransferTask {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DataTransferTask.class, args);
    }
}
```

DataTransferRunner.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.EnableTask;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
@EnableTask
@EnableScheduling
public class DataTransferRunner {

    @Autowired
    public DataTransferRunner() {
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${job_concurrency.fixed-rate}")
    public void run() throws Exception {
       System.out.println("I started running");
    }
}
```

Here is the exception I keep getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@21526f6c has been closed already
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1065) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1176) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchExecutionListenerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(TaskBatchExecutionListenerBeanPostProcessor.java:59) ~[spring-cloud-task-batch-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have @EnableTask, spring will close the context once everything is done running. From the code it looks like you are not running anything explicitly so spring is closing the context before your @Schedule() annotation kicks in.

The fix for that is to tell spring to not close the context at all with `spring.cloud.task.closecontext_enable=false`. This will keep the context open for your scheduled task. 
Some documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#features-lifecycle

One more note about the property. In the documentation it says `closecontext_enable` but after inspecting the logs and the jar, that property has been deprecated and replaced by `close_context_enabled`.

Comment: I tried the same with spring.cloud.task.close_context_enabled=false in application.properties. The context is not getting closed, but the @schdule() is not running.